# How to migrate UUID from Phonegap/Cordova to React Native

Tags: android, ios, cordova, react-native, uuid

My current application was written by Phonegap/Cordova, and used UUID (device.uuid) to identify for some settings (store in server).

I'm writing new application by React Native intend to replace the current. But UUID from React Native is different with Phonegap/Cordova's UUID, if users upgrade to new application, they will lost all their settings.

Is there any idea/solution to migrate UUID?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Say thanks to [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info)
The `getUniqueID()` function return exactly the same device.uuid with cordova-plugin-device in same device